# Hangfire Dashboard .net core - authentication works locally, not on server

Tags: hangfire

I've implemented authentication for Hangfire Dashboard as recommended (the Dashboard isn't viewable on the server without authentication).

It wasn't working on the server, so I just set Authorize to always be true:

In startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //Other stuff here
    app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
    {
        Authorization = new[] { new MyAuthorizationFilter() }
    });
}
```

In my own class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Used for Hangfire Dashboard only
/// </summary>
public class MyAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, even this gets a 403 error returned - yet it works fine locally. The previous auth also works fine locally but not on the server.

I've searched Google but can't find anyone having this error - how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

for worked like below:

```
class MyAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
        {
            var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();

            // Allow all authenticated users to see the Dashboard (potentially dangerous).
            return httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        }
    }
```

And in startup method use as below:

```
   app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseHangfireDashboard(options: new DashboardOptions()
        {
            Authorization = new IDashboardAuthorizationFilter[]
            {
                new MyAuthorizationFilter()
            }
        });

        app.UseHangfireServer();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Comment: what is the url to see dashboard?

Comment: hangfire dashboard url : ~/hangfire